# xslt record display

Tags: xslt

I have a problem. I get the data from xml then transform it with xslt.

Let us say I have a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <root> 
   <row id="1" fname="Dan" lname="Wahlin"> 
    <address type="home"> 
       <street>1234 Anywhere St.</street> 
       <city>AnyTown</city> 
       <zip>85789</zip> 
     </address> 
     <address type="business"> 
       <street>1234 LottaWork Ave.</street> 
       <city>AnyTown</city> 
       <zip>85786</zip> 
     </address> 
  </row> 
   <row id="2" fname="Elaine" lname="Wahlin"> 
    <address type="home"> 
      <street>1234 Anywhere St.</street> 
      <city>AnyTown</city> 
       <zip>85789</zip> 
     </address> 
    <address type="business"> 
      <street>1233 Books Way</street> 
       <city>AnyTown</city> 
       <zip>85784</zip> 
    </address> 
  </row> 
 </root>
```

And this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>   
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
   version="1.0">   
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>  
   <xsl:template match="/"> 
     <root>  
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
      </root>  
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="row">  
          <row>  
            <xsl:attribute name="id">  
                    <xsl:value-of select="id"/>  
               </xsl:attribute>  
                <xsl:attribute name="fname">  
                     <xsl:value-of select="name/fname"/>  
                </xsl:attribute>  
                <xsl:attribute name="lname">  
                     <xsl:value-of select="name/lname"/>  
              </xsl:attribute>  
              <xsl:for-each select="address">  
                   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>  
               </xsl:for-each>           </row>  
      </xsl:template>  
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can limit this to 3 records, then after 3 records it create a tr tag?

For example:

```
<table> 
<tr> 
  <td>Address1</td> 
  <td>Address2</td> 
  <td>Address3</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
   <td>Address4</td> 
   <td>Address5</td> 
   <td>Address6</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: @crisgomez: Sorry, but your input does not match your desired output. Also, your stylesheet is doing a verbose identity transform. So, the question is not clear and you have low rate which discourages guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="address">  
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

You should have something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="address">
<xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 1">
<tr>
<xsl:call-template name="printAddress">
<xsl:with-param name="address" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="printAddress">
<xsl:with-param name="address" select="following-sibling::*[position() = 1]"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="printAddress">
<xsl:with-param name="address" select="following-sibling::*[position() = 2]"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</tr>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And of course you have to have template printAddress somewhere.

This should give you an idea on how to solve it. The point is to process every n-th item (chosen by position() mod n) and explicitly process n following items at once (chosen by following-sibling::*[position() = x]), wrapping them in tr. Notice that it is important to compare mod result with 1, since position starts counting from 1.

Comment: what is "galleryItem"? is this souhld exist in my stylesheet?

Comment: This is just a copy-paste from my own template which creates 3 column table of images from a simple list, which is the same situation as you have. As I wrote, it should just give you an idea of how to do it, you should be able to apply it for your situation yourself.

Comment: It is quite confusing to just post a stylesheet for totally different input.  The least you could do would be to adapt your technique for the given input data.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: You can see, that adapting it to his "totally different input" means changing 3 names. crisgomez asked a very good question, which can be tricky even to experienced developer, so it deserves an answer. But I also suspect him of not having much interest in the xsl or the community. The point was to provide a valuable answer while not doing his homework instead of him (in my work time, by the way).